# words dos not exist in a doc2vec model when a document is added iteratively to the model

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

I wrote the following code to build a Doc2vec Model iteratively. As I read in [this page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/4xPzZiemH1k), if the number of tokens is more than 10000 in  a document then we need to split tokens and repeat the label(s) for each segment.

The length of tokens is more than 10000 for most of my documents.I try to split my tokens by writing the following code.But I got error which shows the tokens after 10000 is not considered in my model.

```
    def iter_documents(top_directory):
        mapDocName_Id=[]
        label=1
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_directory):
            for fname in files:
                print fname
                inputs=[]
                tokens=[]
                with open(os.path.join(root, fname)) as f:
                    for i, line in enumerate(f):          
                        if line.startswith('clueweb09-en00'):
                            if tokens:
                                i=0
                                if len(tokens)<10000:
                                    yield LabeledSentence(tokens[:],[label])
                                else:
                                    tLen=len (tokens)
                                    times= int(math.floor(tLen/10000))
                                    for i in range(0,times):
                                        s=i*10000
                                        e=(i*10000)+9999
                                        yield LabeledSentence(tokens[s:e],[label])
                                    start=times*10000
                                    yield LabeledSentence(tokens[start:tLen],[label])
                                label+=1
                                tokens=[]
                        else:
                            tokens=tokens+line.split()
                    yield LabeledSentence(tokens[:],[label])
class docIterator(object):
    def __init__(self,top_directory):
       self.top_directory = top_directory

    def __iter__(self):
       return iter_documents(self.top_directory)

allDocs = docIterator(inputPath)

model = Doc2Vec(allDocs, size = 300, window = 5, min_count = 2, workers = 4)
model.save('my_model.doc2vec')
```

I test my model with the following code then I got this error:

```
model= Doc2Vec.load('my_model.doc2vec')

#print model['school']
print model['philadelphia']
```

I got a vector as result of school but I got this error for philadelphia. philadelphia is in tokens after index 10000.

```
2017-02-27 13:59:36,751 : INFO : loading Doc2Vec object from /home/fl/Desktop/newInput/tokens/my_model.doc2vec

2017-02-27 13:59:36,765 : INFO : loading docvecs recursively from /home/fl/Desktop/newInput/tokens/my_model.doc2vec.docvecs.* with mmap=None

2017-02-27 13:59:36,765 : INFO : setting ignored attribute syn0norm to None

2017-02-27 13:59:36,765 : INFO : setting ignored attribute cum_table to None
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/fl/git/doc2vec_annoy/Doc2Vec_Annoy/KNN/CreateAnnoyIndex.py",
line 31, in <module>
     print model['philadelphia']   File "/home/flashkar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py",
 line 1504, in __getitem__  
return self.syn0[self.vocab[words].index] 
KeyError: 'philadelphia'
```

Comment: Are you sure your `docIterator` is doing what you think it is? Leaving Doc2Vec out of it, can you find items in your `allDocs` that include the token 'philadelphia'? (For example, what does `sum(1 for doc in allDocs if 'philadelphia' in doc.words)` return?)

Comment: @gojomo you are right the _docIterator_ does not work as I think. Could you please explain more how can leave _Doc2Vec_ out of it. The resul of your example is zero.

Comment: That the result is zero means your iterator is broken: none of the resulting `LabeledSentence` instances include the word 'philadelphia'. So it's not a problem with Doc2Vec at all, and simply running that test has already "left Doc2Vec out of it". Fix your iterator so that some of the items truly include 'philadelphia' , & then Doc2Vec will have a word for it after training. I suggest making a tiny version of your source files, with just a few elements (and at least one that has >10000 tokens. Then tinker with your iterator until you're getting the expected `LabeledSentence` items.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by dividing documents to documents with length 10,000 but with same document identifier. Therefore, I do not check the length of tokens.